# Count number of elements in a list inside a DataFrame's column

Tags: python, list, dataframe, apache-spark, count

I have a `DataFrame` with the following format:

| ID | ID_links |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [10] |
| 1 | [11, 12, 13] |
| 2 | [14, 15] |
| 3 | [16] |
| 4 | [17, 18, 19, 20] |

How could one know how many IDs have an ID_links that has more than one element ? In other words, what is the percentage of IDs that have a ID_links containing more than 1 value in that list ?

Pseudo code:

- Go through each line of the DataFrame
- Count the number of elements in the list, if the number of elements is only one do nothing, else add 1 to a counter
- Divide the counter value by the length of the DataFrame

How could one implement that in Python/Spark ?

Answer (score 0):

Better than iterating over all rows of your DataFrame is to use `numpy.where` like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
                   'ID_links': {0: [10], 1: [11, 12, 13], 2: [14, 15], 3: [16], 4: [17, 18, 19, 20]}})
np.where(df.ID_links.map(len) > 1)
```

output:

```
(array([1, 2, 4]),)
```

You can take the number of elements in that list and divide by the number of rows in your DataFrame to get your desired output

```
where = np.where(df.ID_links.map(len) > 1)
len(where[0]) / len(df.index)  # 0.6 = 60%
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)